# the role i created for wordpress doesn't show my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, roles

I have created a custom role for wordpress, but I don't know a method to give it permissions to access my plugin section.

**what do you mean ?**
In the sense that even adding all the possible permissions, the menu of my plugin is not visible and therefore it is not possible to access the settings

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show us what you actually did, not just give us an overly vague verbal description.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will allow you to add a custom role called "Plugin Manager" with permission to manage plugins.

```
 add_role(
        'plugin-manager',
        'Plugin Manager',
        [
            'activate_plugins',
            'update_plugins',
            'install_plugins',
            'delete_plugins',
            'edit_plugins',
            'upload_plugins'
        ]
 );
```